# Logsitic Regression Interaction Term

Tags: interaction, sas

I am working on an analysis where I would like to know whether an intervention acts differently across levels of income (5 levels total). I'd like to do this for females only, and adjust for age. In the end, I'd like to obtain an odds ratio for each of the 5 levels of income, comparing the treatment to the control. Here is what I have so far:

```
PROC LOGISTIC data=trial;
  WHERE Intervention>. and Income>. and Age>. and Outcome>. AND Sex=0;
  CLASS Income (ref='5') Age (ref='5') / param=ref;
  MODEL Outcome(EVENT='1')=Intervention Income Age Intervention*Income / expb;
RUN;
```

This gets me an OR for the first 4 levels of income, but not the reference group. I feel like I should be using a contrast statement or something like that, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I am not familiar with the SAS syntax, but aren't ORs upposed to be "the average increase in odds after exposure when compared to the reference group"? Meaning that the OR for the reference group is not defined because it is used as the reference to represent the relative increase in odds when comparing to other groups.

Comment: It is 1.00. It is a "ratio" because the reference group's odds works as the denominator. The ratio of its odds to itself is 1.00. Given it really does not serve any purpose interpretation wise, it is usually omitted or replaced by a label like "reference".

Comment: Also, just to capture the income effect there should be 9 odds ratio and then the 1.00 from the reference group, not just 4. Assuming the intervention is binary.